# handleExit() function not working correctly

Tags: python, sys

I'm basically trying to code a C2 server to learn about python networking and actually python basics.
I come from C and Java and I dont really know python best practices lol, I know that i'm running functions recursevely but i don't really know how i should do what i want.
Basically the concept is handling commands, but catching "CTRL+C" too. When i "CTRL + C" or type exit i want to terminate my program and close sockets/threads but it isn't working, the prompt's line is blinking as something is still running... Ik that it isnt sys.exit(0) fault but i dont get why this isnt working.

```
import socket
import threading
import os
import sys
from pyfiglet import figlet_format

serverSocket = None
clientSocket = None
acceptThread = None
clientAddress = None

def handleInput():
    i = input("SmoothArmy => ").lower()
    if i == "exit":
        handleExit()
    elif i == "help":
        helpCommand()
    elif i == "listen":
        startListener(9001)
    else:
        print("That command doesn't exist.")
        
def helpCommand():
    print("List of available Commands:\n")
    print("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n")
    print("help                          :    Shows available Commands\n")
    print("exit                          :    To terminate session\n")
    print("listen <port>                 :    Listen on a port\n")

    #put stuff before these line
    print("------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n")
    
def startListener(port):
    try:
        global serverSocket
        global acceptThread 
        serverSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        serverSocket.bind((socket.gethostname(), port)) 
        serverSocket.listen(10)
        print(f"listening on port {port}...")
        acceptThread = threading.Thread(target=acceptClients)
        acceptThread.start()
        pass
    except:
        print("There was an error starting socket...")
        pass 
    

def acceptClients():
    while True:
        global clientSocket
        global clientAddress
        clientSocket, clientAddress = serverSocket.accept()
        print(f"Connection from {clientAddress} has been established!")


    
def handleExit():
    try:
        i = input("\nDo you want to exit? (y|n) ")
        if i == "y": 
            if acceptThread != None and clientSocket != None and serverSocket != None:
                acceptThread.stop()
                clientSocket.shutdown(1)
                clientSocket.close()
                serverSocket.shutdown(1)
                serverSocket.close()
                sys.exit(0)
            else:
                sys.exit(0)
        else:
            pass
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        handleExit()

print(figlet_format("SmoothArmy", font="standard"))
print("         __ ")
print(" _(\    |@@|")
print("(__/\__ \--/ ")
print("   \___|----|  |   __")
print("       \ }{ /\ )_ / _\\")
print("       /\__/\ \__O (__")
print("      (--/\--)    \__/")
print("      _)(  )(_")
print("     `---''---`")
print("\n")

while True:
    try: 
        handleInput()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        handleExit()
```

Comment: To debug this, add `print("BYE"); sys.exit(1)` to the beginning of `handleExit`. Does the message `BYE` get printed?

Comment: Which operating system are you using?

Comment: yes i tried that, it is printing, i'm using windows

Comment: The only correct way to mark something solved is to click the checkbox by an answer. Do not edit "solved" into titles. (If neither answer is quite right, you can add your own and then accept that).

Comment: Don't put "Solved" in the title. Instead, click the checkmark by the best answer to [accept it](/help/accepted-answer), which basically marks the question as solved. If it's your own answer, you'll need to wait 48 hours.

Comment: If none of the current solutions have solved the problem, but you found a solution you can always add your own solution and accept that instead.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `while True:` loop: it never finishes, thus your program never exits. To fix it, replace the loop condition.

Do it like this:

```
keep_running = True
def handleExit():
   global keep_running
   ...
   keep_running = False
   ...

while keep_running:
   try:
       handleInput()
   except KeyboardInterrupt:
       handleExit()
```

Comment: i tried that but it still is not working... handleExit() gives problems only after running the startListener() function though. and i think there is some problem with the accept thread but i'm not sure

Comment: Then add lots of `print(...)`s, and see which one is reached. If the last one is reached, and it still doesn't exit, then add `sys.exit(0)` to the end.

Comment: Don't forget to add a `print(...)` between each line of `handleExit`. Some of those cleanup calls may be hanging infinitely. As soon as you determine which one hangs, ask a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

```
def startListener(port):
    try:
        global serverSocket
        global acceptThread 
        serverSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        serverSocket.bind((socket.gethostname(), port)) 
        serverSocket.listen(10)
        print(f"listening on port {port}...")
        acceptThread = threading.Thread(target=acceptClients)
        acceptThread.start() 
        sys.exit(0)
        print("Here")
    except Exception as e:
        print("There was an error starting socket...")
        print(e)
        pass
```

"Here" is not printed...

Comment: I actually had to put daemon=True to make the thread run in background. Thanks for helping though!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).